# "Get 50 widgets free and $y thereafter" vs "$y, first 50 widgets free"

Tags: copywriting, pricing

Is there any evidence that the order of this promotion copy matters?

For example, let's say I want to give away 50 widgets for free and start charging $10/month thereafter.  Which copy generally converts better?

*Case A*

> **Get 50 widgets FREE**
>
> $10 per month thereafter

*Case B*

> $10 per month
>
> **First 50 widgets FREE**

In *Case A*, there's an immediate call to satisfy a "what's in it for me?"
In *Case B*, there's a recency effect.

Obviously, a split test would provide more information, but that requires resources.

Comment: I'd say the first option will convert better, but this is like the definition of "let's do some A/B testing!"

Comment: I think that even if someone is able and willing to share evidence that it matters, it will be based on test results from very specific situations. It's always better to have your own evidence, even if resources are scarce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, it's similar to asking a user to try your product for free for a few days and then pay x dollars per month/year as the case may be. Here is a link which you might find useful
https://medium.com/@elise.musumano/ab-testing-growth-experiments-for-saas-8a2ac2ac97f0

The idea is not to push users to pay but invite them to try and leave it upto them to decide. If the product is good enough, not much persuasion will be required.

So in your case it definitely should be option A. If you do not have resources to test out, you can try creating a test and ask people on reddit in specific forums or invite people you know to test. Platforms like what users do offer a free 7 day trial with no credit card. You could request tests for free ofcourse you will have limited participants but it will still give you an idea whether you are headed in the right direction. That's what I have been doing in the past few months.